# Is there a flood fill outlining algorithm for constructing a polygon?

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, flood-fill

Is there a flood fill like method of generating an outline around the object? I'm trying to detect an object in an image and outline it. I'm currently successful with highlighting it but don't know how to outline. I'm using QT C++ and would like to construct a QPolygon of the points at the edges.
My code so far:

```
 while(!stack.empty())
{
    auto curr = stack.pop();
    const auto x = curr.first.x(), y= curr.first.y();
    if(x>=maxX || y>=maxY || x<minX || y<minY || memo[x+y*img.width()])
    {
        continue;
    }
    auto currColor = orig[x+y*img.width()];
    auto diff = colorDifference(currColor, curr.second);
    if(diff < 40)
    {
        memo[x+y*img.width()] = true;
        stack.push(make_pair(QPoint(x-1,y),currColor));
        stack.push(make_pair(QPoint(x+1,y),currColor));
        stack.push(make_pair(QPoint(x,y-1),currColor));
        stack.push(make_pair(QPoint(x,y+1),currColor));
        changed[x+y*img.width()] = filler; //highlight pixel, need to be replaced with outlining
    }
}
```

Comment: As you mentioned "image", erode/dilate comes into my mind which are operations on pixels. I googled a bit but the first hits were all related to OpenCV. However, erode/dilate can be implemented by yourself - no necessity to pull in OpenCV for this. (You even could use the source code of OpenCV to cheat...) ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OpenCV API, **cv::findContours()**.(It's based on [Satoshi et al., 1985](https://www.nevis.columbia.edu/%7Evgenty/public/suzuki_et_al.pdf))

Call **cv::findContours()** on the image you labeled. It returns points of all contours(outlines).(Be careful to filter out trivial contours in the tree of contours such as a root node.)

See the official tutorial, [Contours Hierarchy](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html).